# Start a new MATLAB session without opening the editor window from the last session

Tags: matlab

When I'm working on a MATLAB session with some open tabs in the editor window, I'm having a strange issue.  If another MATLAB session is launched, it auto-opens the same tabs in a new editor window.  How do I disable this using MATLAB preferences?

I have already checked all options in preferences.

Preferences > Editor/Debugger --> **Disabled** 'On restart reopen files from previous MATLAB session'

Why is this setting not persisting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, while MATLAB is open, it keeps track of the files that are loaded into the editor as well as the display parameters for each of them. This information is stored in the following location.

```
fullfile(prefdir, 'MATLABDesktop.xml')
```

There is an entry for every file that you currently have open in an active MATLAB editor.

```
<Client Class="com.mathworks.mde.editor.EditorViewClient" Dock="yes" Group="Editor" Guest="no" SelectionOrder="15" Show="yes" Singleton="no" StatusBarShowing="yes" TearOff="no" Title="C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2015a\MATLABDesktop.xml">
    <Location Context="docked" Maximized="yes" Type="floating"/>
    <Location Context="floatingIn" Maximized="yes" Type="floating"/>
    <ClientData EditorFileName="C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2015a\MATLABDesktop.xml"/>
</Client>
```

When you select the preference to not remember files on restart, this causes all of these entries to be removed from this file when the application quits.

When you have more than one instance of MATLAB (the same version) running at a time, they are both relying on the same file. So when you open up a file with one instance, then launch a new instance, the new instance loads that file and populates the editor state from that.

As far as fixing this behavior, I think it may be difficult. You could *maybe* edit your startup.m file to remove all of those entries from the `MATLABDesktop.xml` file. Even then, I'm not sure how that affects the stability of the other running instance.

**Script to Perform This Cleaning**

If you want a script that is able to do this while preserving all other settings that exist in the configuration file, the following should work.

```
filename = fullfile(prefdir, 'MATLABDesktop.xml');
xml = xmlread(filename);

% Find ALL <Client> entries in the file and determine "Class" attribute
clients = xml.getElementsByTagName('Client');
clients = arrayfun(@(x)clients.item(x-1), 1:clients.getLength, 'uni', 0);
classes = cellfun(@(x)char(x.getAttribute('Class')), clients, 'uni', 0);

% Find all EditorViewClient <Client> entries
func = @(x)isempty(regexp(x, '\.EditorViewClient$', 'once'));
toremove = ~cellfun(func, classes);
clients = clients(toremove);

% Remove all client entries that need to be removed
for k = 1:numel(clients)
    parent = clients{k}.getParentNode();
    parent.removeChild(clients{k});
end

% Write the remaining data back to the file
xmlwrite(filename, xml);
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I modify this from startup file? Is it like flushing out everything under MATLABDesktop.xml?  I have asked Mathworks as well about this feature and no reply yet from them.

Comment: @Maddy I definitely wouldn't recommend blowing away the entire file because it includes a lot of other settings. I have updated my post to include a script which should be able to remove *only* the offending entries. You can either copy/paste that into your startup script or put it in a separate function and call it from your startup.